# weird formating in UITextView for Hebrew characters

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsstring, unicode-string

I'm having a weird output inside my UITextView, when using hebrew characters, if I print it in the console i get something correct:

"אסף השמן said 13 hours ago:"

but when displayed inside my UITextView It gets printed like that:

[image: UITextView output]

Any idea ?

```
UITextView * textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y , width, g.height)];
[textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];    
[textView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[textView setFont:font];
[textView setTextColor:color];
[textView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
[textView setText:textContent];

[scrollView addSubview:textView];
```

Comment: Could you log  the exact string that gets shown in the text view?

Comment: I don't get you. I have a screenshot included already.

Comment: why are you aligning to the right? align left   
````[textView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];````

Comment: because Hebrew is a right-to-left reading language, so you have to align to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hebrew is a right-to-left leading language, what begins at left in a latin language will begin at right in Hebrew. The text will be displayed at the right of your component if you choose a right-to-left leading language. Maybe the way you print the content does it the way you expect it to be, but in your screens it will be displayed in a right-to-left manner due to its format.

Comment: I'm not using autolayout.